# Seeing ClosedPoolError when using urllib3.PoolManager

Tags: python, multithreading, urllib3

When using urllib3.PoolManager (python 2.7, urllib3 version: 1.21) I frequently encountered ClosedPoolError exceptions. After reading the code I'm inclined to believe that this is expected since the connection object returned may have been evicted by the pool's cache by the time it is used.

I have reproduced the error into the following script:

https://pastebin.com/aJggVHuv

```
#!/bin/bash

set -ex

TEST_DIR=/tmp/urllib3_bug
mkdir -p $TEST_DIR
cd $TEST_DIR
virtualenv .virtualenv
. .virtualenv/bin/activate
pip install urllib3==1.21

# Starts 3 threads with pool size = 2
echo 'from urllib3 import PoolManager
import threading
from threading import Thread

pool_manager = PoolManager(num_pools=2)


def start(url):
    print "Getting", url, "on", threading.current_thread().ident
    return pool_manager.urlopen("GET", url)


thread1 = Thread(target=start, args=["http://localhost:9998"])
thread2 = Thread(target=start, args=["http://localhost:9999"])
thread3 = Thread(target=start, args=["http://localhost:10000"])

thread1.start()
import time
time.sleep(1)
thread2.start()
thread3.start()
' > start.py

# Simulates preemption by sleeping the thread
echo '303a304,308
>         import time
>         import threading
>         print "Simulating preemption on", threading.current_thread().ident
>         time.sleep(3)
>         print "Waking up on", threading.current_thread().ident' | patch $TEST_DIR/.virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py -
rm -f $TEST_DIR/.virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.pyc


python start.py
```

I create a pool of size 2, then run 3 threads, each of which connecting to a different URL. The first thread should encounter a ClosedPoolError.

(The patch inserts sleep() to reliably reproduce a preemption on the first thread).

Comment: I suspect your original guess is correct. To remedy this, you can make the PoolManager larger, or have a separate PoolManager per thread. I haven't had a chance to take a really close look so I'll let someone else write up a complete answer.